# Is it possible to prevent certain flows from being cloned

Tags: sandbox-refresh, sandbox-clone

Is it possible to prevent certain flows from being accessed when someone clone a sandbox?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **No.**

If you refer to below from [Clone a Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_clone.htm&type=5) documentation, it copies over all metadata (emphasis mine) and you don't have any way to select/de-select any particular metadata.

> When you clone a sandbox, **all** its data and **metadata** are copied to the new sandbox