# Protecting Flows from being copied (Managed Package)

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, package, isv

Managed Packages say they provide IP/Code Protection for Flows but to what extent? If I deploy a flow into a customer environment, can they not just go in there, copy the flows they want and then eventually uninstall the managed package?

Is there any way to prevent a customer from doing the above?

This was a similar question posted on this post, so I am also linking it for visibility.
[Is it possible to prevent certain flows from being cloned](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248711/is-it-possible-to-prevent-certain-flows-from-being-cloned)

Comment: All packaged flows are automatically protected UNLESS you make them templates.

Comment: Hi @PhilW could you point me to a doc on how they are protected? Can a customer edit or copy them?

Answer (score 2):

If you review the "packageable components" documentation for [flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_flow) you will see:

---

| Can This Component Be Updata or Removed After Package Version Promotion |  |
| --- | --- |
| Component Has IP Protection | Yes, except templates |

**Editable Properties After Package Promotion or Installation**

Only Package Developer Can Edit

- Entire flow

Both Package Developer and Subscriber Can Edit

- Flow Label
- Description
- Status

Neither Package Developer or Subscriber Can Edit

- Flow API Name
- URL

---

The key points are that a flow in a managed package has IP protection unless you make it a template. If it isn't a template, the subscriber cannot view or edit the flow at all. They can relabel it, update its description and change its status.

If you make the flow a template then the subscriber can clone it then edit the clone (but they still cannot edit the original). This is the only way that the subscriber is able to see a flow's details. So if you don't want them to know how a flow does its magic, just don't make it a template in your managed package.